# Autostart Apps in order - Windows Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, operating-system

Is there some way to autostart apps in Vista so you can control which one is started first, second, third etc. For example if I want to start Outlook, Visual Studio, Dreamweaver, IE, Firefox in that order, and to have them appear in the taskbar like that.

I added them into the autostart-folder but Vista didn't start the apps in the order I wanted it?

/C

Comment: Yes, on SU. But if it's any consolation it can't be done (with Windows). You'll have to hack your own startup script and remove anything you want to customize from msconfig.

Comment: There are tools that allow you to move the application buttons on the taskbar, since that what you seem to want in the end. Or use Windows 7. This is build in.

Comment: Ok, what tools are that for Vista?

And what did you mean, can you move around buttons in the taskbar by default in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it on your own, you can write a simple vbscript or javascript that launches programs you want in order, and autolaunch just that script.

I tested the following script on my Windows 7 machine. Should work on Vista also. Create a new text file with content similar to the sample, name it ***myStartScript.vbs*** or something like that.

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
progList = Array("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE",_
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE",_
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")
For Each prog in progList
    'WScript.Echo "File Name: " & prog
    shell.run """" & prog & """", 1, false
    WScript.sleep 1000 'one second
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

There are scores of programs (freeware/shareware/commercial) available to do that.
[A random example is "Absolute Startup"](http://www.absolutestartup.com/)

They work by making THAT program the first and only thing that is started up by Windows, and then starting the rest of the stuff themselves.

But this question belongs on Server Fault or whatever Windows admin companion to SO is.